# Displaytag excel export not working on Websphere 8

Tags: export, apache-poi, displaytag, websphere-8, spring-4

I am using displaytag with Spring 4 MVC in my application. The displaytag is supposed to support excel export of the table data. The export feature when tested on my local Tomcat 7 server works perfectly but does not seem to work on the Websphere 8 server. I have the necessary poi jars in my project.

Following is the displaytag.properties entry for exporting:

```
export.types=csv excel xml pdf rtf
export.excel=true
export.excel.class=org.displaytag.export.ExcelView
export.excel.filename=EnquiryExport.xls
```

Comment: For me, Excel exportis working when the user saves the file from Prompt. It is not working when the user click on Open option.

Comment: @Jothi : Can you please elaborate. For me clicking on the export link does not do anything on Websphere 8 whereas it works perfectly on Tomcat 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the issue! Just added the following header to the response for excel export and it worked like a charm!

```
response.setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
response.setContentLength(new Long(file.length()).intValue());
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=export.xlsx");
```